React 18.2.0 dynamically generate form while onClick - form to represent deeply nested JSON
I have a JSON object which is deeply nested. I want to display input fields with respect to the JSON values. To traverse through the deeply nested JSON object I used recursion and collected all processed input fields to set it into a state to display in the main return of the module. However, it is throwing Too many re-renders to infinite loop. Uncaught run time errors.
I have tried various methods such as,

Storing displayFrom in displayProperties in a separate const and used that const into setDisplayForm.

Applied various conditions in the main return of App module such as typeof properties[ key ] === 'object' in the conditional rendering

Used useMemo to wrap the displayProperties function from causing too many re-render issue.


I have implemented the same in stackblitz please take a look at my code and comment. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-kjyz2y?file=src%2FApp.jsx&terminal=dev
There is an const input it makes the code looks bigger and complex but it is just a JSON nested object. The actual logic and code looks like below,
import { useState } from 'react';
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg';
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
const [displayFrom, setDisplayForm] = useState();

const input = {} // a deeply nested JSON object

const displayProperties = (properties) => {
return (
  <>
    {Object.keys(properties).map((key, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <span>{key === 'label' ? properties[key] : null}</span>
        <span>
          {JSON.stringify(properties[key]).includes('properties') ||
          JSON.stringify(properties[key]).includes('label')
            ? displayProperties(properties[key])
            : null}
        </span>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
);
};
const builtForm = () => displayProperties(input);
setDisplayForm(builtForm);

return <>{displayFrom}</>;
}

export default App;


Here is a preview of the app we will make. The user can supply any arbitrary object as a starting point. As the user changes values in the form, the deeply nested object is updated -



preview








an isomorphism first
In another Q&A we go through the process of flattening and unflattening any nested object using a fromJS and toJS interface. The details of that process will not be covered in this post. We start by flattening the object -
{
  users: [
    { name: "Alice", roles: ["a", "b"], phone: { mobile: 123 } },
    { name: "Bob", roles: [], phone: { home: 456, mobile: 789 } }
  ]
}

const flat = fromJS(example) // ✅

[
  ["users", 0, "name", "Alice"],
  ["users", 0, "roles", 0, "a"],
  ["users", 0, "roles", 1, "b"],
  ["users", 0, "phone", "mobile", 123],
  ["users", 1, "name", "Bob"],
  ["users", 1, "phone", "home", 456],
  ["users", 1, "phone", "mobile", 789]
]

And toJS can reverse the operation -
const newExample = toJS(flat) // ✅

{
  users: [
    { name: "Alice", roles: ["a", "b"], phone: { mobile: 123 } },
    { name: "Bob", roles: [], phone: { home: 456, mobile: 789 } }
  ]
}

react component
Now we make a React Form component to operate on the flat state. Run the code example below and watch the nested object update -


const example = {
  users: [
    { name: "Alice", roles: ["a", "b"], phone: { mobile: 123 } },
    { name: "Bob", roles: [], phone: { home: 456, mobile: 789 } }
  ]
}

function Form({ data }) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => fromJS(data))
  const updateState = index => event => {
    setState(prev => updateArr(prev, index, record =>
      [...record.slice(0, -1), event.target.value]
    ))
  }
  return <div>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(toJS(state), null, 2)}</pre>
    <form>
      {state.map((record, index) => {
        const key = record.slice(0, -1).join(".")
        return <label key={key}>
          {key}
          <input value={record.at(-1)} onChange={updateState(index)} />
        </label>
      })} 
    </form>
  </div>
}

// dependencies
function updateArr(arr, index, func) {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    func(arr[index]),
    ...arr.slice(index + 1),
  ]
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129261/633183
function fromJS(v, r = []){
  switch (v && v.constructor) {
    case Object:
      return Object.entries(v)
        .flatMap(([ k, v ]) => fromJS(v, [ ...r, k ]))
    case Array:
      return v.flatMap((v, k) => fromJS(v, [ ...r, k ]))
    default:
      return [[ ...r, v ]]
  }
}

function toJS(t){
  return t.reduce((r, v) => merge(r, toJS1(v)), {})
}

function toJS1([ v, ...more ]) {
  if (more.length)
    return set(
      Number.isInteger(v) ? [] : {},
      [ v, toJS1(more) ]
    )
  else
    return v
}

function merge(l = {}, r = {}) {
  return Object
    .entries(r)
    .map(([ k, v ]) => isObject(v) && isObject(l[k]) ? [ k, merge(l[k], v) ] : [ k, v ])
    .reduce(set, l)
}

const isObject = t =>  Object(t) === t

const set = (t, [ k, v ]) => (t[k] = v, t)

// run
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<Form data={example} />)
div { display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: start;}
label { display: block; width: 300px; }
input { float: right; width: 100px; }
label ~ label { margin-top: 0.5rem; }
form { background: #ffc; padding: 1rem; }
pre { width: 250px; }
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



remarks
In ~20 lines of React, we made our first Formik clone. You can see how the Form component could be extended to render a more sophisticated HTML representation of the nested values, or to allow for the addition/removal of new fields. Once the input object is represented as flat state, the challenges of working with it in React are greatly reduced.
To make the demo run online, all dependencies are included in this small code paste. Separate the generic functions into their respective modules to keep the React component focused on its task.

alternative implementation
You requested that the form maintains the nested object shape, even as local state. Here's an update that incorporates the necessary changes.
This immutable update helper will be the foundation for constructing our recursive setState calls. It works by allowing an immutable, functional update on our data objects (and arrays) -
function update(data, key, value) {
  if (data != null && typeof data == "object")
    return Object.assign(
      Array.isArray(data) ? [] : {},
      data,
      { [key]: value instanceof Function ? value(data[key]) : value }
    )
  return data
}

Next we write the entry point of our Form, which accepts any arbitrary data to use as the initial state -
function Form({ initialData }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(initialData ?? {})
  return <div>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    <form>
      <RecursiveForm data={data} setData={setData} path={[]} />
    </form>  
  </div>
}

This depends on RecursiveForm which does a simple case switch on the input data's type -
function RecursiveForm({ path, data, setData }) {
  if (data == null)
    throw Error("form data cannot be null or undefined")
  if (typeof data == "object")
    return Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
      <RecursiveForm
        key={key}
        path={[...path, key]}
        data={value}
        setData={next => setData(prev => update(prev, key, next))}
      />
    ))
  if (typeof data == "string")
    return (
      <label>
        {path.join(".")}
        <input
          value={data}
          onChange={e => setData(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
    )
  if (typeof data == "number")
    return (
      <label>
        {path.join(".")}
        <input
          value={String(data)}
          type="number"
          onChange={e =>
            setData(prev => {
              const next = Number(e.target.value)
              if (Number.isNaN(next)) return prev
              return next
            })
          }
        />
      </label>
    )
  if (typeof data == "boolean")
    return (
      <label>
        {path.join(".")}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={data}
          onChange={e => setData(e.target.checked)}
        />
      </label>
    )
  throw Error(`unsupported form data: ${data}`)
}

⚠️ You can see we are careful to maintain the type of the deeply nested values. For this reason, we do not support objects with null or undefined fields because our dynamic form cannot possibly know which type to use when a value is supplied. In this case we throw an error.
demo, take two
Run the demo below to verify the result in your browser -


const example = {
  users: [
    { name: "Alice", roles: ["a", "b"], phone: { mobile: 123 }, active: true },
    { name: "Bob", roles: [], phone: { home: 456, mobile: 789 }, active: false }
  ]
}

function Form({ initialData }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => initialData || {})
  return <div>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    <form>
      <RecursiveForm data={data} setData={setData} path={[]} />
    </form>  
  </div>
}

function RecursiveForm({ path, data, setData }) {
  if (data == null)
    throw Error("form data cannot be null or undefined")
  if (typeof data == "object")
    return Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
      <RecursiveForm
        key={key}
        path={[...path, key]}
        data={value}
        setData={next => setData(prev => update(prev, key, next))}
      />
    ))
  if (typeof data == "string")
    return (
      <label>
        {path.join(".")}
        <input
          value={data}
          onChange={e => setData(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
    )
  if (typeof data == "number")
    return (
      <label>
        {path.join(".")}
        <input
          value={String(data)}
          type="number"
          onChange={e =>
            setData(prev => {
              const next = Number(e.target.value)
              if (Number.isNaN(next)) return prev
              return next
            })
          }
        />
      </label>
    )
  if (typeof data == "boolean")
    return (
      <label>
        {path.join(".")}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={data}
          onChange={e => setData(e.target.checked)}
        />
      </label>
    )
  throw Error(`unsupported form data: ${data}`)
}

function update(data, key, value) {
  if (data != null && typeof data == "object")
    return Object.assign(
      Array.isArray(data) ? [] : {},
      data,
      { [key]: value instanceof Function ? value(data[key]) : value }
    )
  return data
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<Form initialData={example} />)
div { display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: start;}
label { display: block; width: 300px; }
input { float: right; width: 100px; }
label ~ label { margin-top: 0.5rem; }
form { background: #ffc; padding: 1rem; }
pre { width: 250px; }
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



typescript
At this level of complexity, typescript can add additional assurances that data is being handled correctly -
import * as React from "react"

export type State = 
  | { [key: string]: State }
  | State[]
  | number
  | boolean
  | string

export type FormProps = {
  initialData?: State
}

export type RecursiveFormProps = {
  path: (string | number)[]
  data: State
  setData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<State>>
}

export function update(
  data: State,
  key: number | string,
  value: React.SetStateAction<unknown>,
): State {
  if (data != null && typeof data == "object") {
    return Array.isArray(data)
      ? Object.assign([], data, {
          [key]: value instanceof Function ? value(data[key as number]) : value,
        })
      : Object.assign({}, data, {
          [key]: value instanceof Function ? value(data[key as string]) : value,
        })
  }
  return data
}

export default function Form(props: FormProps) { ... }

export function RecursiveForm(props: RecursiveFormProps) { ... }


I don't want to flatten the JSON object at the same time, I wanted it to be execute it in recursion. ( You have given a great answer. However, due to SO limitation I couldn't post the entire JSON since it was exceeding 3000 characters. ). { "label": "Simple label", "type": "object", "properties": { "detailsRequest": { "label": "detailsRequest", "type": "object", "required": true, "isSensitive": false, "properties": { "location": { "label": "location", "type": "string", "required": true, "isSensitive": false } } } } } Likewise, may properties will be in JSON.

@CommonMan understood. I made an update to the post that performs the update without flattening the state.

The problem is likely due to the fact that you can’t use an index as a key value.
Try something like this:
import { useState } from 'react';
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg';
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [displayFrom, setDisplayForm] = useState();

  const input = {}

  let id = 1;

  const displayProperties = (properties) => {
    return (
      <>
        {Object.keys(properties).map((key) => {
          id++;
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              <span>{key === 'label' ? properties[key] : null}</span>
              <span>{JSON.stringify(properties[key]).includes('properties') || JSON.stringify(properties[key]).includes('label') ? displayProperties(properties[key]) : null}</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
  };

  return <>{displayProperties(input)}</>;
}

export default App;

I tried this on the provided stackblitz I got this output.
Is this the desired output?

If the objects already have some kind of ID or unique identifying value, you can also use that instead of the id variable.

this doesn't works!

I tried it on stackblitz and it worked fine for me.
Could you provide some more info on the problem.
